# Estimating the total variation distance between two continuous distributions with identical support

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Say I am given two datasets $S_{\mathcal{Q}}$ and $S_{\mathcal{P}}$ sampled from the continuous distributions $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ respectively. Assume that both $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ have the same support, namely some compact set of $\mathcal{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Is there an efficient way to measure the total variation distance between $P$ and $Q$ using the samples  $S_{\mathcal{Q}}$ and $S_{\mathcal{P}}$?

My first thought was just to perform density estimation then numerical integration. I guess histograms would be efficient as the integration would be cheap. But is there a more efficient way with theoretical guarantees that perhaps avoids density estimation all together?

Comment: Why do you want to use 'total variation' (TV)? Why not  Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic?So far in my study, I don't recall any estimator would give you an approximate TV based on data samples and I don't think it is possible without additional hypothesis on the regularity of $Q$ and $P$

Comment: I want to estimate the TV distance as it occurs in generalisation bounds for domain adaptation problems (see Theorem 1 here: https://www.alexkulesza.com/pubs/adapt_mlj10.pdf). I wanted to measure the total variation distance between two distributions and see if changes in TV distance empirically correlate with the efficacy of domain adaptation. I am aware you can empirically estimate TV distance for distributions absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure via KDE's (see footnote 7 in section 5 of this paper: http://php.scripts.psu.edu/users/b/k/bks18/euclid.ejs.1347974672.pdf)